# How to show that a random factor is not needed in the model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I collected data from an experiment where I showed one of four videos (`condition`) to a person and asked them to predict how it ended / assign one of three labels to the video (`prediction`). I asked each person to make a prediction after they had completed watching 25%, 50%, 75%, and 100% of the video (`completed`). I collected 330 responses total.

From a more technical perspective, I have a dataset with two independent variables, and one dependent variable. **`condition` is categorical** and has 4 levels measured between subject; **`completion` is ordinal** with 4 levels (although the underlying construct is continuous - should I model it as a continuous variable?) and measured within-subject. The dependent variable **`prediction` is categorical** with 3 levels. I could make it dichotomous, since I have ground truth on the correct prediction, so I could code it as `correct/incorrect`.

My Hypothesis is that slope of correct predictions over time differs significantly between conditions, i.e., for some videos people make better predictions earlier compared to other videos.

Since this is a repeated measures experiment with a categorical dependent variable, I am using a Generalized Linear Mixed-Effects Model (`glmer` in R) to fit my data. Here are the models I'm currently fitting:

```r
interaction <- glmer("prediction ~ condition*completion + (1|id)", data=data, family="binomial")
main_effects <- glmer("prediction ~ condition + completion + (1|id)", data=data, family="binomial")
baseline <- glmer("prediction ~ completion + (1|id)", data=data, family="binomial")
```

I then compare `main_effects` to `baseline` and `interaction` to `main_effects` using `anova()`. Am I actually testing my hypothesis like this? (I still get confused easily with linear models)

My **main question**, however, is: I am getting the error: `boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular`, for `main_effects` and `interaction`. Am I interpreting this correctly as: The data doesn't support participants as a random factor, and I should fit a `glm` instead?

Comment: You don't seem to have time included in your model. It may not fix the singular fit problem, bur I would have thought that time plays a part in the data generation process. Have you tried including it as a fixed effect ?  Moreover, does the response (correct/incorrect) vary for each participant ?

Comment: @RobertLong `completion` is time in this case. Initially a person observes the first 25% of the video and makes a prediction, then the same person observes the first 50%, makes a prediction, and so forth. Also yes, the response varies between and within subject for each level of the independent variables (some change their response as more of the video is revealed), with exception for the 100% level. Predicting the end after you have observed the end doesn't seem to cause much variance ...

Comment: Ahh OK ! So are you using the 2 level or 3 level variable  as the response ? It is difficult to say much more without actually seeing the data. Can you share it ?

Comment: @RobertLong Yes I have two 4 level variables as inputs and one 3 level variable as response. I think it will be okay to share the data, but I will have to double-check with my supervisor :) How would I share it?

Comment: Wait, so the problems with singularity are with a 3-level response variable ? This may be causing the problems - that would be a multinomial model and glmer doesn't fit those.. What happens when you convert it to binary.

Comment: @RobertLong Singularity happens in both cases; if I recode the 3-level response variable into a binary response variable then all three models suffer from singularity.

Comment: Ok well plesse share your data if possible

Comment: @RobertLong here is a google spreadsheet with the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kgzaUG9SCqqRwmE6mtPBPUg8nar-NLiMaYi77niU0sQ/edit?usp=sharing It should import in R just fine if you download it as a .csv

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have fitted a model to your data using the `mixed_model` function from the `GLMMadaptive` package without receiving any error or warning, and compared the output to that produced by `glmer`(with the singular fit):

(data is available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kgzaUG9SCqqRwmE6mtPBPUg8nar-NLiMaYi77niU0sQ/edit?usp=sharing) )

```
> library(lme4)
> library(GLMMadaptive)

> dt <- read.csv("PilotDataStacked-results.csv")

> dt$id <- as.factor(dt$id)
> m0_glmer <- glmer(isCorrect ~ condition + completion + (1|id), data = dt, nAGQ = 20, family="binomial"(link = logit))

> m0_GLMMadaptive <- mixed_model(fixed = isCorrect ~ condition + completion, random = ~ 1 | id, data = dt,
               family = binomial())
> summary(m0_glmer)

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 1160, groups:  id, 290

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      2.171244   0.233476   9.300  < 2e-16 ***
conditiongreen  -0.831986   0.222863  -3.733 0.000189 ***
conditiongreen2 -1.139616   0.224589  -5.074 3.89e-07 ***
conditionred    -0.753830   0.215395  -3.500 0.000466 ***
completion      -0.050959   0.003675 -13.867  < 2e-16 ***

> summary(m0_GLMMadaptive) 

Random effects covariance matrix:
               StdDev
(Intercept) 0.1508784

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std.Err  z-value    p-value
(Intercept)       2.1786  0.2349   9.2745    < 1e-04
conditiongreen   -0.8342  0.2248  -3.7110 0.00020646
conditiongreen2  -1.1428  0.2265  -5.0454    < 1e-04
conditionred     -0.7560  0.2173  -3.4792 0.00050283
completion       -0.0512  0.0037 -13.8441    < 1e-04
```

As you can see, the results are essentially the same. It is a mystery why `glmer` obtains a singular fit. The variance of the random intercept estimated by `mixed_model` is quite small, so that is my only idea, however it is not *extremely* small, so if I were you I would want to investigate a bit more before proceeding with either model. Ben Bolker is one of the authors of `lme4` so he might see this message if I ping him in a comment, which I will do, but if not you might want to ask for  input from `lme4` specialists on the `R-sig-ME` mailing list:
https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mixed-models

Also Dimitris Rizopoulos (author of `GLMMAdaptive`) may have some input. I will also ping him.

Edit: As to your other questions:

> completion is ordinal with 4 levels (although the underlying construct is continuous - should I model it as a continuous variable?)

Yes, you are losing information by modelling it as ordinal.

> Am I actually testing my hypothesis like this? (I still get confused easily with linear models)

Since your hypothesis is whether the slope of `completion` changes at different levels of `condition` then your interest should center on the interaction between them. This will be easier to interpret if you switch to continuous `completion`.

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos  do you have any insight ?

Comment: @BenBolker do you have any insight about why `glmer` is having trouble with these data ?

Comment: Perhaps worth considering the `blme` package as well? It imposes a reasonable prior on the random intercept that pushes it away from 0. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/blme/

Comment: Another question: Does @FirefoxMetzger actually have the continuous version of the outcome or are they saying that there is an underlying (latent) continuous distribution, suggesting that the generalized mixed model approach is correct?

Comment: @ErikRuzek I must admit, I am not sure I understand the question correctly. The outcome is binary (success/failure); so I model it as predicting the probability of success, and hence use logistic regression. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger Erik is asking about the completion variable.

Comment: @ErikRuzek Yes, `completion` is a continuous variable. It refers to how much of the video (in %) a person has seen when predicting how it will end. They do see the full video, but for logistic, i.e., experimental design, reasons I only measure it at 4 points in time.

Comment: @RobertLong - FYI, I don't think users will notified unless they've already interacted on the post. See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: @Justin  Ahh thanks for that. At least I have learned something new ! :)

Comment: A *very* quick exploration shows that `glmer` gets a fit with log-likelihood 0.32 units greater than `GLMMadaptive`'s fit - a suggestion that there may (?) be multiple modes and `glmer` may (?) be finding the better one.  Next thing to try would be to start each method at the other's optimum.  (This assumes that the log-likelihood computations themselves match.)